# Does cloning elements (with 'href' resources defined) or reading them from the DOM using jQuery load the resources from the remote server?

Tags: jquery

Does cloning elements (with 'href' resources defined), such as an image or link, or reading them from the DOM using jQuery, [does it] load the resources from the remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clone an element, i.e., you copy it from somewhere and paste it into another part of the DOM, then browser sends another request to the server. But caching here helps us a lot.

However, reading something from DOM, does not trigger any HTTP Request.

Answer (score 0):

No, because if you're cloning an element, that element already exists and has been seen by the browser, so the resource has already been loaded. It won't be loaded again for subsequent requests to that url.